# AOL and E-Mail Marketing

Tags: email, marketing, bulk-email

I offer a paid subscription newsletter service that sends e-mails daily. I have had trouble in the past and currently with AOL E-Mail Address users and did not know if there is anything specific that I can do so that AOL will allow these e-mails through to the user. I would like to note that the messages are *not* getting marked as SPAM. They simply do not show and I do not receive any bounces from the e-mails. They seem to just disappear. Now with that said here is what steps I have taken:

- Contacted the company I send the e-mails through to see if they can tweak their settings
- Asked the end user to add my e-mail to their Address Book (my email is a valid e-mail)
- Setup Domainkeys and SPF for my site
- Checked for "spammy" words and phrases etc
- Checked for the blacklisting of the mail server IPs (they are not)

I only have this issue with AOL users; Gmail, MSN, Yahoo, etc do not give me these issues. Anything I can do to improve the rates would be very beneficial to my company and the users who pay to receive these messages. I have attempted to contact AOL and all I get back is a very general canned response that tells me nothing or says there is no issue. Is there anything I can do to "help" my e-mails out with AOL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had similar issues in the past. Doing every single thing I could do on AOL's Postmaster site seemed to help things a bit: http://postmaster.aol.com/

That's also the place to contact them about these issues. Maybe you've already gone through that site, but you hadn't mentioned it.